# Cambiar css para mostrar número celular en Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, safari

Sitio web www.maipoadventure.cl en el footer se muestra el número celular, pero en dispositivos apple con Safari se muestra en blanco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En styles.css tienes un comentario en el selector ".extreme-left p" usando doble slash en lugar de "/* comentario */"
Es posible que esto esté ocasionando el comportamiento errático en Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Los teléfonos deberías de meterlos en una etiqueta "anchor" y después hacer target a ellos con el respectivo selector:

HTML:

```
<p class="p-telefonos"><a href="tel:+1-555-555-5555">1-555-555-5555</a></p>
```

CSS:

```
.p-telefonos{
    color: #000;
 }

a[href^="tel"] {
  color: inherit; /* Hereda el color del elemento padre, en este caso "p-telefonos" */
  text-decoration: none; /* Quita el subrayado. */
  /* CSS adicional aquí */
}
```